# RxAndroid best practice migrating asyncTask

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Hello guys I am trying to get the hang of it, But I am beggining to wonder what is the best

`way to fetch->store_database->update ui`

with RxAndroid, usually I create an IntentService or manage a separate pool of thread independent to the UI and post the changes either with broadcast or with a Bus provider, I am wondering how to achieve this with RxAndroid since usually is very simple code to retrieve but never how to handle post this code, is there a common higher order function that is save to post/pre treat the stream of data?

Answer (score 1):

I usually organize my code in "Managers". In you scenario I would have a `FetchManager`, returning an `Observable` to retrieve the data. I would have a `StorageManager`, returning an `Observable` with storing result.

I would `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` on the fetching `Observable`, retrieve the data and update the UI.

You can use `concatMap` or `doOnNext()` to handle the storing.